# How to order Filter in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating different `Filter` `@Bean`, and would like to enforce the execution of a specific filter before the other filter:

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public Filter getLoggingUuidFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        //...
    };
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
public Filter getLoggingRequestFilter() {
    return new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
}
```

Result: Filter2 executes before Filter1. Why?

Comment: Ok, so `@Order` is not for ordering the filter, but one has to additionally create a `FilterRegistrationBean` and `filter.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);`.

Answer (score -2):

from spring documentation of @Order

> Annotation-based ordering is supported for specific kinds of
>   components only — for example, for annotation-based AspectJ aspects.
>   Ordering strategies within the Spring container, on the other hand,
>   are typically based on the Ordered interface in order to allow for
>   programmatically configurable ordering of each instance